# How best to describe a person who wants to prove you wrong with half-baked information?

Tags: word-request

For example, a person uses a word to describe something and another person believing what they know pushes to argue for a misuse of the word only to use part of the definition. This causes a the two people to argue or verbally attack each other. As for the person who used the word, they have to go out of their way to find the word as well as the proper definition and use of the word to prove they used the word appropriately.

The question here is what is a word used for people that do not gather full information as well as doing things to cause a heated argument?

Comment: The arguments themselves might be "half-baked". I'm not sure whether this is in common use anymore, but you might describe the person as someone who tends to "go off half-cocked". I feel like there are other idioms, but none is jumping to mind at the moment.

Comment: yes, i can understand that. This person has a tendency to start arguments and then try to play the victim after, there is so many words and i feel at a loss when i try to describe this person just using one word.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think you're going to find a single word for such a complex concept. Does your language have a single word for it? "Hotheaded", "impulsive", "impetuous", "reckless", "hasty" all carry elements of what you're talking about, but none of them encompass the full idea. Even more near-synonyms exist that might also be something like what you want, but again, none of them encompass the full meaning you intend.

Comment: ok, well thank you for your time and help.